# How best to allocate dynamic memory in c++

Tags: c++, templates, generics

which is better for memory allocation in c++ for classes and template. malloc() or new; can malloc() be used to allocate memory for classes or template?

Comment: Point 1: You should mention why it doesn't work. Point 2: Don't use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: in c++ you should use operator new. also see comment by Park...

Comment: What doesn't work for you? It works for me once I include the header for malloc and add the 2 missing braces. http://ideone.com/DaIHvC

Comment: This only works for *trivial* classes

Comment: @RaphaelM undefined behaviour can include appearing to "work"

Comment: nothing undefined there yet, they are both trivial afaik. If he wants to know more he should include where his problem actually is.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this, although not the way you do it, and in any case it's not really beginner stuff. The reason your approach does not work is that an uninitialized slab of memory is not the same as a valid object. But before I continue:

**IMPORTANT STYLE NOTE:** I am going to leave aside for the sake of brevity the usual memory management mechanics (smart pointers et al) that **you should stick to religiously as a beginner** (and, in fact, as an expert, but they don't need to be told). Do not use code like what I'm about to show here in production (not without all the necessary bookkeeping around it), or things **will** break in ways that are horrible to debug. I'm only doing it because doing it properly would obscure the mechanics I'll try to show.

The difference between a slab of uninitialized memory and a valid object are, in a broad sense, class invariants. What this means is that a class defines certain properties for its objects that these always fulfill. For example, a string class will generally guarantee that the pointer to its data will not be a dangling pointer, and that its size will not reported to be larger than the block of memory that pointer points to. An uninitialized slab of memory cannot guarantee either of those things, and that is why we have *constructors*. A constructor is a function that constructs an object into an uninitialized slab of memory, fixing these invariants, and most of the time it is called for you automatically. If you write

```
Foo f;
```

memory is obtained from the stack (simplified terminology; please bear with me, language lawyers), and the default constructor `Foo::Foo()` is called on that piece of memory. Similarly, if you write

```
Foo *p = new Foo();
```

`operator new` obtains memory from the heap and calls the constructor on that piece of memory. Possibly it does more than that, but let's leave that possibility aside for now.

So what goes wrong in your code? Well, when you write

```
*obj = A();
```

this is an assignment. It assumes that there is a valid object `*obj` that a newly constructed object can be copied into. This is not the case, because `obj` points to an uninitialized slab of memory.

So, before you can use your uninitialized slab of memory like an object, you have to construct one into it. This is possible, and it is called **placement new**. The syntax looks like this:

```
new(obj) A();
```

And later you have to call the destructor (the constructor's counterpart; its purpose is to undo what the constructor did) manually like so:

```
obj->~A();
```

...after which obj will again point to uninitialized memory, and (unless the class is buggy) all necessary cleanup has been done. Except giving back the slab of memory, because that was allocated outside the constructor/destructor duo. Normally it would happen automatically at the end of the scope (for automatic variables like `f` above) or `delete` would do it for you (for dynamic storage objects like `*p` above), but since you did the allocation yourself, you have to do the deallocation yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `malloc()` for allocatiog C++ objects shall be avoided.

Rewrite your `main()` using C++ practice:

```
A *obj = new A();  // get memory and initialize the object 
B<int> *objb = new B<int>();  // same
```

This works better and is easier to read !

***Remark:***  Statements like `*obj=A();` may call a class specific assignment operator, which would assume that `*obj` was already initialized by a constructor and is in a valid state.  If memory was simply aquired by `malloc()`, this assumption is not fulfilled.

Comment: Yes, `malloc` isn't C++. But I would say that the overuse of `new` isn't good C++ either. Just do `A obja;` and `B<int> objb;`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid You are of course right.  However, in my answer I assume that OP asks this because he needs dynamic allocaltion: local variables are not suitable for all purposes. Let's avoid opinion based discussions please.

Comment: Hi @Christophe. I understand and agree with you. My comment wasn't very helpful or complete. I guess the minimal change required to fix the question's code is to use *placement* `new`. Going a step further, the `malloc` and placement `new` could both be removed and replaced with a simple `new`. Finally, we could simply get rid of `new` and leave everything on the stack. That gives us three different answers.